# Сортировка массива. Перенести цифры

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

**Задание:**

Задан массив из k символов.Создать два новых массива: в первый перенести все цифры из исходного массива, во второй - все остальные символы.

**Проблема: Происходит бесконечное зацикливание в этом куске кода**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
std::cout<<"Vyvod massiv b:";
std::cout<<std::endl;
i = 0;
while(b[i])
 std::cout<<b[i]<<' ';
 std::cout<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"Vyvod massiv c:";
 std::cout<<std::endl;
 i = 0;
 while(c[i])
 std::cout<<c[i]<<' ';
 std::cout<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы же нигде не изменяете `i` - вот и получается:

```
i = 0;
while(b[i]) std::cout<<b[i]<<' ';
```

Пока `b[0]` не нуль, выводить `b[0]`. А с чего оно вдруг может стать нулевым? Вот и выводим...

Сделайте, например,

```
for(int i = 0;b[i];++i) std::cout<<b[i]<<' ';
```